# Java Choosing a recursive function

Tags: java, string, recursion

I have here two different recursive functions for reversing a string in Java:

```
    Long ms1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String str1 = reverse1(str);
    ms1 = System.currentTimeMillis() - ms1;

    Long ms2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String str2 = reverse2(str);
    ms2 = System.currentTimeMillis() - ms2;

    System.out.println("Input: " + str);
    System.out.println("  Length: " + str.length());
    System.out.println("Reverse 1:");
    System.out.println("  " + herp + " function calls");
    System.out.println("  " + ms1 +  " milliseconds");
    System.out.println("Reverse 2:");
    System.out.println("  " + derp + " function calls");
    System.out.println("  " + ms2 +  " milliseconds");
}
public static String reverse1(String str){
    herp++;
    if(str.length() == 1) return str;
    return reverse1(str.substring(str.length()/2)) + reverse1(str.substring(0, str.length()/2));
}
public static String reverse2(String str){
    derp++;
    if(str.length() == 1) return str;
    return reverse2(str.substring(1)) + str.charAt(0);
}
```

Given a string of length 5000, this is the program's output:

```
Input: ...
  Length: 5000
Reverse 1:
  9999 function calls
  16 milliseconds
Reverse 2:
  5000 function calls
  52 milliseconds
```

Now why is the function with double the function calls ~3x faster? How should I be structuring my recursive functions for max speed in Java?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have division rounding errors?

Comment: both of the reverse functions correctly reverse the input string, if that's your question

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you warm up the JVM prior to conducting these tests? Although if it hasn't been warmed up, I would expect to see relatively slower times for the first test over the second.

Comment: What happens to the times if you call reverse2 before reverse1?

Comment: It's just a simple main function, there is no warm-up.

Comment: Actually, if I switch them, the time difference is even larger. Reverse 1 takes 10 ms and Reverse 2 takes 187 ms, when Reverse 2 goes first.

Comment: My wild guess is that most of the time here is actually spent on creating (and storing) strings: the first function is better with it, as length of its arguments falls quickly (5000 - 2500 - 1250...), when in the second function it's (5000 - 4999 - 4998...).

Comment: It needs to be said:  In languages where variables are by default mutable, recursion is not about speed.  It is about simplicity.  If you're worried about performance over simplicity, particularly in a language like Java, you should be aware that an iterative solution will be faster almost every time.  In this case, an iterative `reverse()` could be O(N).

Comment: Is it possible that System.currentTimeMillis is not giving me reliable information?

Comment: I'm fully aware that an iterative solution would be much better. This is more of an academic exercise.

Comment: @EricB: Yes, I'd be a bit wary about timing so short intervals with `currentTimeMillis`. Though on most reasonably modern systems it does seem to provide millisecond precision, it's actually [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29) to have unknown ganularity: _Note that while the unit of time of the return value is a millisecond, the granularity of the value depends on the underlying operating system and may be larger. For example, many operating systems measure time in units of tens of milliseconds._

Comment: Alright, I'll keep that in mind. Unfortunately if I try to test on a string that's much longer, I get a stack overflow.

Comment: @cHao: I threw up a benchmark of your implementation in a separate answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a matter of good old algorithmic analysis. Your `reverse1` should run in O(n logn) time, whereas `reverse2` needs O(n²) time, so the longer the string to reverse is, the more dramatically faster than `reverse2` will `reverse1` be.

The resource usage is dominated not by the number of calls, but by the time taken to copy characters into the new String object created at each string concatenation operation. The string concatenation in `reverse2` works on longer strings *on average* than the one in `reverse1`, so its total execution time is longer.

- In `reverse1`, every character is copied log2(n) times (where n is the length of the original string), since the depth of the recursive call tree is about log2(n).
- In `reverse2` every character is copied a number of times equal to its position in the original string (±1, which I don't care about). That makes n/2 copies on average of each character.

For large n, log2(n) is much smaller than n/2, and therefore `reverse1` tends to be faster.

Comment: Thanks! This will make a great interview question about recursion and run time complexity.

Comment: @Eric just note that this depends on the string implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Roughly 50% of the calls of the first type end without doing any work, because `str.length() == 1`. This makes the number of calls with non-trivial work roughly equal. If you move `derp++` and `herp++` calls to after the exit condition, you'd get the number of "non-trivial" calls, and they will be equal.

Other calls will go faster, too, because on average they would be concatenating shorter strings, making up for the 3x difference.

Answer (score 1):

@HenningMakholm's answer is excellent, but I just wanted to throw this out there, based on a comment about iterative methods and immutable strings by @cHao. This would probably be most appropriate for a comment but I wanted the space real estate of an answer...

```
public static String reverse3(String str){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int i;
    for(i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        sb.append(str.charAt(i));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

This iterative method which creates only one immutable `String` object at the end, and runs in `O(n)` time yields the following results:

```
  Length: 5406
Reverse 1:
  10811 function calls
  59 milliseconds
  5406 length correctness test
Reverse 2:
  5406 function calls
  126 milliseconds
  5406 length correctness test
Reverse 3:
  3 milliseconds
  5406 length correctness test
```

Comment: I was considering a char array, considering we already know exactly how big to make it.  But this works too...  :)  and demonstrates how iteration (particularly for problems that favor it) can make recursion look hilariously slow.

Comment: Yes, I wrote an iterative reverse3 using a char array and it easily outperforms the other two.

Comment: I think this also demonstrates how important it is to only make one `String` object at the very end of your process, if possible. It's clearly not simply `O(n log n)` vs `O(n)`... Eliminating the unnecessary `Object` creation and cleanup is why.